# Proving that inclusion is antisymmetric in Coq

Tags: coq, set-theory

I'm a Coq newbie and I'd like to prove that the inclusion relation is antisymmetric, that is: $\forall x\forall y(x\subseteq y\land y\subseteq x\rightarrow x=y)$.

I wrote the following thing:

```
Section Test.
Variable set : Type.
Variable element : set -> set -> Prop.
Definition subset (x:set) (y:set) := forall z:set, element z x -> element z y.
Axiom equality : forall x y:set, x = y <-> forall z:set, element z x <-> element z y.
Theorem inclusion_is_antisymmetric : forall x y:set, subset x y /\ subset y x -> x = y.
Proof.
intros a b.
unfold subset.
intro H.
destruct H as [H0 H1].
```

At this point I get the following output:

```
1 subgoal
set : Type
element : set -> set -> Prop
a : set
b : set
H0 : forall z : set, element z a -> element z b
H1 : forall z : set, element z b -> element z a
______________________________________(1/1)
a = b
```

I'm stuck now because I don't know how to:

- change the goal from $a=b$ to $\forall z(z\in a\leftrightarrow z\in b)$ and then to $c\in a\leftrightarrow c\in b$
- change `H0` from $\forall z(z\in a\rightarrow z\in b)$ to $c\in a\rightarrow c\in b$
- change `H1` from $\forall z(z\in b\rightarrow z\in c)$ to $c\in b\rightarrow c\in a$

That is, I know how to prove this theorem on paper but not with Coq.

Comment: I think `rewrite equality` should get you one step further, after adding `Require Import Setoid` to the top of your script.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to finish the proof by adding: rewrite equality. intro c. split. apply H0. apply H1. Still, I'd like to know if there is any other way of doing this, for example without having to import "Setoid".

Answer (score 6):

```
Theorem inclusion_is_antisymmetric : forall x y:set, subset x y /\ subset y x -> x = y.
Proof.
  firstorder using equality.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer, that only uses basic tactics:

`Theorem inclusion_is_antisymmetric : forall x y:set, subset x y /\ subset y x -> x = y.
Proof.
  intros x y H.
  inversion H.
  apply equality.
  split.
  apply H0.
  apply H1.
Qed.`

For those that don't want to run it through Coq, the proof is fairly obvious, the `equality` axiom is literally the antecedent `subset x y /\ subset y x` with a little bit of obfuscation (the quantification is in sort of the wrong spot, and we can effectively move it with the split).